# Fish: batch rename files with spaces in names using mv and sed

Tags: command-line, scripting, fish

I'm trying to rename multiple files from the command line as follows:

```
for f in *.pdf
    mv $f echo $f | sed 's/\( \)\([0-9]\)/-\2/'
end
```

I got the error:

```
mv: target 'filename' is not a directory
```

It is obvious that target's name has spaces and must be enclosed in quotes to be handled by `mv` command.

What should I do to get this script works?

Comment: if you have already found the cause to you problem is quoting, why can't you just add quotes in your codes to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your script will try to move the file and the file called "echo" to the file, and pipe `mv`'s output to `sed`.

What you want is to run that `echo | sed` in a command substitution, which fish denotes with `()`:

```
for f in *.pdf
    mv $f (echo $f | sed 's/\( \)\([0-9]\)/-\2/')
end
```

> It is obvious that target's name has spaces and must be enclosed in quotes to be handled by mv command.

It is not obvious because it doesn't need to be quoted. Fish does not perform word splitting like bash does. The filename is set once, and then `$f` will always yield the filename as one argument.

Quoting it like `"$f"` would be entirely superfluous.

For command substitutions, it splits them on *newlines* only, not spaces, so unless you have a filename with a newline (*highly* unlikely) you won't have a problem there either.

If you did you'd have to use `string collect` like

```
for f in *.pdf
    mv $f (echo $f | sed 's/\( \)\([0-9]\)/-\2/' | string collect)
end
```

to ensure the command substitution results in one argument.

Comment: It works flawlessly! Thank a lot for the extended answer!